# Error installing SPEI package in R

Tags: r, installation, package

I am trying to install SPEI in Rstudio, version 1.1.414, running on Windows 7. However, I get the following error message in the console:

> install.packages("SPEI")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/xxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     dependency ‘goftest’ is not available
>   also installing the dependency ‘lmomco’

It appears that this "goftest" package is unavailable, so how can I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'goftest' documentation says

> **Depends** R (>= 3.3)

so probably you should upgrade to a later version of R to use the package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/goftest/goftest.pdf

Comment: Of course this is the right answer! Sometimes I forget that R and Rstudio require different upgrades.